# HTML/TS: textarea textContent disappears after creating another textarea or after button click

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, textarea, innerhtml

I have a HTML page which contains a few textareas, but I also add more textareas dynamically. I add more textareas in the html file by using `document.getElementById("textAreas").innerHTML += '<textarea class="textArea"></textarea>';`. The problem is that whenever I create a new textarea, the other newly made textarea their text disappears. But the textareas that are loaded in from the beginning its text does not disappear.

EDIT:

The problem of the disappearing text when pressing the add button is gone. The current problem is that when I click on another button than the add a textarea one, the newly made text disappears.

These are the standard loaded in ones: 
[image]

After pressing the add button 2 times:
[image]

Now I fill in some data:

[image]

So now I have all textareas filled in. The problem in the next image is that the not standard ones their text disappears after clicking on the add button: 
[image]

The text also disappears after clicking on a button. The html and ts file are below:

.html:

```
<ion-content class="master">
  <div class="reportList">
    <div *ngFor="let note of paramReport.notes">
      <textarea class="textArea">{{note}}</textarea>
    </div>
    <div id="textAreas"></div>
    <button ion-button color="avioBlue" (click)="addField()">
      <ion-icon name="add-circle"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-grid>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col col-6>
          <button ion-button block color="avioOrange" (click)="saveAsDraft()">Save as draft</button>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col col-6>
          <button ion-button block color="avioRed" (click)="saveAsFinal()">Save as final</button>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

.ts:

```
addField(){
    document.getElementById("textAreas").innerHTML += '<textarea class="textArea"></textarea>';
  }

saveAsDraft(){
    this.paramReport.isFinal = false;
    this.saveAndSend();
  }

  saveAsFinal(){
    this.paramReport.isFinal = true;
    this.saveAndSend();
  }

  saveAndSend(){
    var textAreaList = document.getElementsByClassName("textArea");
    this.paramReport.notes = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < textAreaList.length; i++) {
      //console.log(textAreaList[i].textContent);
      this.paramReport.notes.push(textAreaList[i].textContent);
    }
    let status: string;
    if (this.paramReport.isFinal) status = "FINAL"; else status = "DRAFT";
    this.reportsProvider.editReportFromList(this.paramReport);
    this.toastCtrl.create({
      message: 'Submitted report with id: ' + this.paramReport.id
      + ' made by ' + this.paramReport.submittedBy + ' as ' + status,
      duration: 2000,
      position: 'top'
    }).present();
    this.navCtrl.push(ReportOverviewPage);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The texts disappear because with the current way to have, you are removing the entire dom nodes, and re-render them with the new text areas. You should use the document.createElement API instead.

```
var textarea= document.createElement("textarea");
textarea.className = "textArea";
document.getElementById("textAreas").appendChild(textarea);
```

Comment: That solved the problem of the disappearing text when adding another textarea. The next problem is that when I click on a button, the text disappears and when I console.log, it logs white spaces @orabis

Comment: So addField works fine now, but you still have problems with saveAsDraft and saveAsFinal?

Comment: yes, after I press one of the buttons the text disappears ... @orabis

Comment: There are some methods such as this.reportsProvider.editReportFromList and this.toastCtrl.create.present, which I am not aware what they do. Is there a form submission in the code? Could you try adding event.preventDefault() at the beginning of each method? You will need to add the event parameters to these methods as well.